# Using esc_attr function

Tags: localization

I want to translate some website to Spanish, and the default translation in 'Settings' doesn't translate everything.
I notice in the code, that where the translation doesn't work there are functions like `esc_attr` or `esc_attr_x` or `___`.
I understand that these functions used to translate texts, but I didn't really get how it is done exactly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wordpress translation should be done in `gettext .po` files (which should be formatted to `.mo` files). Every theme can have it's own "translation domain". Have you read https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to have the text domain along with the render functions (echo function). 
It means that, they should be:

```
esc_attr_e("Text needing to be translated","your_text_domain");<br>
esc_attr_x("Text needing to be translated","your_text_domain");<br>
___("Text needing to be translated","your_text_domain");
```